# method object is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-serializer

I am using ajax to refresh the cart items when cart item is removed. It works well, if i don't response object with image otherwise I get an error `method object is not JSON serializable`. If i use `model_to_dict` for the image part, i get an error `'function' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

here is the code

```
def cart_detail_api_view(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    products = [{
            "id": x.id,
            "url": x.get_absolute_url(),
            "name": x.name,
            "price": x.price,
            "image": x.first_image
            }
            for x in cart_obj.furnitures.all()]
    cart_data  = {"products": products, "subtotal": cart_obj.sub_total, "total": cart_obj.total}
    return JsonResponse(cart_data)

class Furniture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def first_image(self):
        """
        Return first image of the furniture otherwise default image
        """
        if self.furniture_pics:
            return self.furniture_pics.first()
        return '/static/img/4niture.jpg'

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    furnitures = models.ManyToManyField(Furniture, blank=True)
```

I get `'function' object has no attribute '_meta'` error while wrapping `x.first_image` to `model_to_dict`

How do i resolve such issue?

UPDATED

```
class FurniturePic(models.Model):
    """
    Represents furniture picture
    """
    furniture = models.ForeignKey(Furniture, related_name='furniture_pics')
    url = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem, as you know, is at :

```
"image": x.first_image
```

`first_image` is a function, so it can't be converted to JSON. What you want to do is serialize the value returned by `first_image`. So, for that, you need to **call** this function:

```
"image": x.first_image() # note the brackets
```

---

Additionally, I also noticed another issue, at:

```
return self.furniture_pics.first() # will return the image object; will cause error
```

So, you'll have to change that to:

```
return self.furniture_pics.first().url # will return the url of the image
```

**Update:**

`self.furniture_pics.first().url` will return `FurniturePic.url` which is an `ImageField`. You need the url of that picture for serialization. You'd have to do this:

```
return self.furniture_pics.first().url.url # call url of `url`
```

---

As you can see, this is getting confusing. I'd suggest changing the `FurniturePic.url` field's name to `FurniturePic.image`. But, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: That way i got `Object of type 'FurniturePic' is not JSON serializable`. I was hesitated to show different kinds of error in a single question :)

Comment: also tried x.first_image().url which threw `Object of type 'ImageFieldFile' is not JSON serializable` this error

Comment: isn't `self.furniture_pics.first().url` same as `x.first_image().url` ?

Comment: @pri Not always. If `self.furniture_pics` don't exists, `first_image()` will return a string. In that case, `x.first_image().url` will raise an error. But it is rather interesting that you're getting a different error now. Is `self.furniture_pics` a ManyToMany field to another model?

Comment: I did like you said, both `return self.furniture_pics.first().url` and `"image": x.first_image()` but still getting an error `Object of type 'ImageFieldFile' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @pri Updated the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks, naming creates a huge trouble sometimes. I appreciate your suggestion and go with you. Thanks again, it worked now.